# Align origin of highcharts axis

Tags: highcharts

I have two series that should we plotted on the same graph, as is shown in the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hVVA7/2/),
how can I 'sync' the axis so that both '0' (origin) lines align?

I cannot use the linkedTo property because then the values are the same as well, while these should be independent. Only the position of the 0-line should be the same.

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value +'°C';
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: '#89A54E'
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar is done here, for first button: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/5m9JW/

It's not perfect solution, but allows to manage that in `afterSetExtremes`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use min value for second (column) yAxis, with negative value.

Comment: It works with trial and error if you know the values that are being displayed, but this data is dynamic, so it would involve some kind of calculation that depends on how HighCharts decides to position the ticks.